# Find the length of the longest path in the matrix with the consecutive character along with its path

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Given M * N matrix of characters, find the length of the longest path in the matrix starting from the given source.

> Note : All characters in the longest path should be increasing  and
>   consecutive to each other in alphabetical order.            We are
>   allowed to search the next character in all 8 directions.

I have correctly found out the length of the sequence but there is a problem in path. path is not correct.
Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

//Below array details all 8 posible directions
int row[] = { -1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
int col[] = { 1, 0, -1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1 };


int length(char arr[][5], int x, int y, char previous, vector<pair<int,int> > &path, int k)
{
    // x and y must be bounded between 0 to 4
    if( x < 0  || x > 4 || y > 4 || y < 0)
       return 0;

    int l = 0;
    int max_length = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        // storing next character in search
        char ch = arr[x+row[i]][y+col[i]];

        //checking whether ch is the next character in the sequence or not
        if(ch == previous + 1)
        {  
            //if k != path.size() then we have taken back in
            // the sequence so no need to push back character in the path
            if(k == path.size())
              {
                // Pushing co-ordinates of next valid character
                path.push_back(make_pair(x+row[i], y+col[i]));
              }
            else
                path.pop_back();

            l = 1 + length(arr, x+row[i], y+ col[i], ch , path, ++k);
            max_length = max( l, max_length);
        }

    }

    return max_length;
}

int main()
{
    char arr[5][5] = { 
                      { 'd','e','h','x','b'},
                      { 'a','o','g','p','e'},
                      { 'd','d','c','f','d'},
                      { 'e','b','e','a','s'},
                      { 'c','d','y','e','n'}
                    };
    vector<pair<int,int> > path;

    //Pusing source address
    path.push_back(make_pair(2,2));

    int k = 1;

    int Len = length(arr, 2, 2 , arr[2][2], path, k);

    cout << "Length of the Longest sequence is : " << Len + 1 <<endl; 

    //printing the path
    cout << "Path is : "<<endl;
    for( pair<int,int> i : path)
    {
        cout <<"( " << i.first <<","<<i.second <<" )" ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Actual output :

> Length of the Longest sequence is : 6
>      Path is
>         ( 2,2 )( 2,1)( 3,0 )( 3,2 )( 2,3 )( 1,2 )( 0,2 )

Expected output

> Length of the Longest sequence is : 6
>    Path is
>   ( 2,2 )(2,1 )( 3,2 )( 2,3 )( 1,2 )( 0,2 )

There is a extra (3,0) in my output. When I take back from (3,0) , I could not pop it.
 Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `(3,0)` come from? Did you try to step line by line through your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm for building the path cannot work like that. You have some prevision to not destroy the path when backtracking, but when -- after backtracking -- the search deepens again in another direction, the path will become a combination of two paths: the previous branch is not removed from it.

So in your practical case, the first attempt is to go from (2,1) to (3,0). There it finds it can no longer go deeper, but it is the best path so far. Then it backtracks back to (2,1). The path is not shortened (because it still is the best). Then the search deepens again to (3,2). This address is then added to the path, which makes it inconsistent.

It cannot work like that. You need to create a new path when you find a better one, and make sure it never gets altered again. Only when you find a better path, you just replace it completely.

I would also suggest limiting the parameters of your function (`++k` is also a problem -- but we can do without). Instead of mutating a path argument, let the function *return* the longest path. The length can always be derived from it.

So here is how your function could be modified:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

//Below array details all 8 posible directions
int row[] = { -1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
int col[] = { 1, 0, -1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1 };

vector<pair<int,int> > longestPath(char arr[][5], int x, int y)
{
    char previous = arr[x][y];
    vector<pair<int,int> > path; // a new(!) path
    // x and y must be bounded between 0 to 4
    if( x < 0  || x > 4 || y > 4 || y < 0)
       return path;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        // storing next character in search
        char ch = arr[x+row[i]][y+col[i]];

        //checking whether ch is the next character in the sequence or not
        if(ch == previous + 1)
        {  
            vector<pair<int,int> > foundPath = longestPath(arr, x+row[i], y+ col[i]);
            if (foundPath.size() > path.size())
                path = foundPath;
        }

    }
    path.insert(path.begin(), make_pair(x,y));
    return path;
}

int main()
{
    char arr[5][5] = { 
                      { 'd','e','h','x','b'},
                      { 'a','o','g','p','e'},
                      { 'd','d','c','f','d'},
                      { 'e','b','e','a','s'},
                      { 'c','d','y','e','n'}
                    };
    vector<pair<int,int> > path = longestPath(arr, 2, 2);

    //printing the path
    cout << "Path is : "<<endl;
    for( pair<int,int> i : path)
    {
        cout <<"( " << i.first <<","<<i.second <<" )" ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting with the implementation and showing it to us - you should start with the abstract algorithm (and data structures), and make sure to the best of your ability that *that* is sound. Also, I suggest not focusing as much on the sequence of individual instructions and loop variables but on the bigger-picture of it.

So, here's a relatively naive algorithm:

- Run a phase for each node in the (potential) path: So, in your case, 26 phases at most.
- At each phase, you hold the set of matrix locations where paths can reach; and you derive the set of locations where those paths can reach with another step. In other words, you're advancing a "front" of many paths, one step at a time.
- The phase action can be effected either by trying to move forward from each previous-front position (e.g. checking which 'f' in the front have a neighboring 'g'); or by trying to move backwards from each matrix element with the appropriate value for the phase (e.g. search which g's in the matrix are adjacent to f's which are in the previous front.)

This is different than your approach in the sense that there's no recursion on the individual paths. Such recursion could blow up really quickly. And while it's true that your path can't be more than 26 characters long, the principle is problematic. Suppose you had a diagonal matrix looking like this:

```
abcde  ...
bcde  ...
cde  ...
de ...
e ...
.
.
.
```

Any combination of left and down moves is a valid path; so there are 2^k paths of length k starting from a. Do you want to invoke your `longestPath()` 2^26 times? Not if you don't have to... :-(